# MergeAdapter certain statments running at wrong time

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm using MergeAdapter to dispaly a List with section headers. This list is displaying fine but sometimes certain things inside the getView method are being triggered when they shouldn't sometimes.

Here's the bit what is triggering.

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
   ...
    try {
        JSONObject thisRow = items.get(position);
        ...
        View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        JSONObject alterations = thisRow.getJSONArray("alteration").getJSONObject(0);


        // This if statement gets trigger when it shouldn't
        if (!alterations.getString("text").equals("false")) {
            CharSequence currText = time.getText();
            time.setText(currText+" vs" +ID);
            Log.d("FUApp", "Alterations 'text' isn't false at "+ID);
            Button alter = (Button) centreView.findViewById(R.id.is_alt);
            String s = String.valueOf(position);
            alter.setText(s);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            alter.setLayoutParams(lp);
            alter.setOnClickListener(myListener);
        }
    ...
    return centreView;
}
```

I set a label to dispaly the value of position and here's a screen capture from my app.

[image]

As you can see the button is being displayed the position is 43, the button shouldn't be showing there at all.

I'm completely stumped as to why this is happening. Can anyone help me figure this out?

EDIT: It seems to be the if statement is getting triggered on the row what enters the screen when the position (e.g 35) leaves the view. Still not sure how to stop it appearing though yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted my old answer as it wasn't good at all. Caused me problems.

The problem was when the view was being recycled I wasn't resetting the button back to 0dp

I added these lines

```
 Button alter = (Button) centreView.findViewById(R.id.is_alt);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
        alter.setLayoutParams(lp);
        final JSONObject alterations = thisRow.getJSONArray("alteration").getJSONObject(0);
        if (!alterations.getString("text").equals("false")) {
```

And it works as it should now.